# gganimate:combine barplot with lineplot

Tags: r, gganimate

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

set.seed(321)
year <- 2001:2021
value <- runif(n = length(year))*100%>% round(digits = 2)

df <- data.frame(year, value) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(value))


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = cumsum)) +
  transition_states(year) +
  shadow_mark()
```

How to get an animate for both bar and line plots along the years, there is an error with the code above.
Error in transform_path(all_frames, next_state, ease, params$transition_length[i],  :
transformr is required to tween paths and lines

Answer (score 0):

Install `transformr() package`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
library(transformr)

set.seed(321)
year <- 2001:2021
value <- runif(n = length(year))*100%>% round(digits = 2)

df <- data.frame(year, value) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(value))


df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = cumsum)) +
  transition_states(year) +
  shadow_mark()
```

Comment: Thanks, but no line anim.   0sgeom_path: Each group consists of only one
observation. Do you need to adjust the group
aesthetic?
                                                      
Inserting image 100 at 9.90s (100%)...
Encoding to gif... done!

Comment: With transformr and the following code, there is no shadow for barplot. ```df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = cumsum)) +
  transition_reveal(year) +
  shadow_mark()
```